# Energy delivered by a LED in Joule

Tags: led, laser

Please help me with calculation

I read in the link
https://www.thorlaser.com/LLLT/calculating-LLLT-dosage.htm

A 500mW laser with a beam area of 0.25Cm2 used for 20 seconds 
delivers 40 J/cm²
A 200mW laser with a beam area of 0.1Cm2 used for 20 seconds 
delivers 40 J/cm²
A 30mW laser with a beam area of 0.015Cm2 used for 20 seconds 
also delivers 40 J/cm²
Each of these probes apparently apply the same "dosage". However, the total energy delivered is clearly different [10 Joules, 4 Joules and 0.6 Joules respectively].

--------So what it is the formula for energy delivered by laser or LEd ??
many thanks

Comment: Energy = Power * Time, if you capture all the energy in the beam.

Comment: Just take note of the fact that the problem presents different ***affected*** areas. Since the *energy per unit area* is the same, the only thing affecting the total energy delivered is the differences in area. Or think of this another way. Suppose I had two laser pulse weapons on a space-based orbital platform. One can deliver \$10^{20}\:\text{J}\$ over the area of exactly ***one*** building in a city and the other one can deliver \$10^{20}\:\text{J}\$ over the area of one building in a city but do it for ***all*** of the buildings in the entire city at once. Which delivers more total energy?

Comment: Some of the confusion for the calculation is directly related to the article's number two issue: "Dosage expressed as J/cm² is inadequate."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the input you're given, you can calculate

$$\rm Energy = Power \times Time$$

What you're calling dosage is apparently

$$\rm Dosage = \frac{Energy}{Area}$$

which is why you can get equal dosages for different energy absorbed, if you just scale the area accordingly.

Comment: In other words a larger dosage is delivered (in equal time) if the beam size is larger. Even when the specified energy per unit area is listed as being equal.

Comment: @Nedd, not according to these definitions. A larger beam with the same energy per unit area would provide more total energy, but the same *dosage* as defined in OP's article.

Comment: Your answer help me a lot.. now.

Comment: Sorry about voting.I do not know exactly to use.Please give me a LINK how to use vote section of answer.Thanks to all for answers